# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:Error creating order number；

Tags: java

brief introduction：
I am making a small mall, there is always an error can not be resolved, create order number tool class error, I tried to Google know this error, run time can not find the appropriate class, I paste down the code and detailed errors below:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public OrderDto create(OrderDto orderDto) {
    //implement Here is the wrong report.
    String orderId = OrderNumberUtil.getUniqueKey();
    BigDecimal orderAmount = new BigDecimal(0);
    //订单下可能有很多商品
    for(OrderDetail orderDetail : orderDto.getOrderDetailList()){
        ProductInfo productInfo =productInfoService.getProductInfo(orderDetail.getProductId());
        if(productInfo == null){
            throw new SellException(ResultEnum.PRODUCT_NOT_EXIST);
        }
        //计算订单总价

        double prices= new BigDecimal(productInfo.getProductPrice().toString()).doubleValue();
        orderAmount= BigDecimalUtil.mul(orderDetail.getProductQuantity(),prices).add(orderAmount);

        //订单详情数据插入到数据库 orderDetail
        orderDetail.setDetailId(OrderNumberUtil.getUniqueKey());
        orderDetail.setOrderId(orderId);

        BeanUtils.copyProperties(productInfo,orderDetail);
        orderDetailRepository.save(orderDetail);
    }


    OrderMaster orderMaster = new OrderMaster();
    orderMaster.setOrderId(orderId);
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(orderDto,orderMaster);
    log.info("订单号为:{}========================>>计算得出总价格是:{}",orderId,orderAmount);
    orderMaster.setOrderAmount(orderAmount);
    orderMaster.setOrderStatus(OrderStatusEnum.NEW.getCode());
    orderMaster.setPayStatus(PayStatusEnum.WAIT.getCode());
    orderMasterRepository.save(orderMaster);

    // Inventory deduction 
    List<CartDto> cartDtoList = orderDto.getOrderDetailList().stream().map(e ->
                new CartDto(e.getProductId(),e.getProductQuantity())
            ).collect(Collectors.toList());

    productInfoService.decreaseStock(cartDtoList);
    return orderDto;
}




public  class OrderNumberUtil {

    /**
     *  OrderNO
     * @return
     */
    public static synchronized String getUniqueKey(){
        Random random = new Random();
        Integer number = random.nextInt(900000) + 100000;
        log.info("---orderNo:{}",System.currentTimeMillis()+String.valueOf(number));
        return System.currentTimeMillis() + String.valueOf(number);
    }


}
```

========================================================================

```
The tool class for generating order numbers was not compiled to match what Google said, but I can't think of the reason why debug was trying to identify the problem here.
```

This is a detailed error in the console.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUZmt.png)

Comment: You need to include the complete error message and stacktrace for the exception in your question.   (That will most likely explain the immediate problem ... if not the root cause.)

Comment: The explanation will be either that some class is missing from you classpath, or that there was an earlier failure in some classes static initialization.   (Other explanations are possible, but highly unlikely.  In all cases, the clues should be in your logs.)

Comment: getUniqueKey() might be simply a getter method for a unique key, and what you need here is creation of such a key thru some provideKey() setKey(String key) like method.